# Skipped 552 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I'm making recyclerview and it has 50 items

I run my app without glide and onClickListener like these

```
/*
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {        
            val intent = Intent(holder.containerView.context, VideoActivity::class.java)

            intent.putExtra("videoid",list[position].videoid)
            holder.containerView.context.startActivity(intent)
        }
*/
```

and

```
/*
Glide.with(holder.containerView.context)
     .load(list[position].thumbnail)
     .into(holder.containerView.thumbnail)
*/
```

but it still has the same problem

**here's my main code**

```
val adapter = PlaylistAdapter(playlistList!!)
playlistListView.adapter=adapter
playlistListView.layoutManager= LinearLayoutManager(this)
```

**This is my Adapter**

```
class PlaylistAdapter(val list: ArrayList<PlaylistModel>): RecyclerView.Adapter<PlaylistViewHolder>(){

    init{

    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PlaylistViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_playlist,parent,false)
        return PlaylistViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.count()
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PlaylistViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.containerView.title.text=list[position].title
        Glide.with(holder.containerView.context).load(list[position].thumbnail).into(holder.containerView.thumbnail)

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {

            val intent = Intent(holder.containerView.context, VideoActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("videoid",list[position].videoid)
            holder.containerView.context.startActivity(intent)

        }
    }




}
```

So, what do I do wrong? Can you give me some advice about this?

Thank you.

Comment: 552 frames is nearly 10 seconds. Nothing in that code snippet is likely to be the cause of this delay.

Comment: @CommonsWare but when I check with Log, that message come appear after my main code

Comment: There must be something different. What are you doing apart from setting this adapter?

Comment: The posted code should not cause any problems itself. Do you do sth else in main thread? how to you layout the screen?

Comment: @S-Sh that code is all thing about layout the screen.  How can I find what code cause that problem?

Comment: @Jun such error is very common if the RecyclerView is not laid out correctly (e.g., is inside NestedScrollView or ViewPager). So, some information about screen layout would be useful